# Получение JSP с помощью @Controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, controller

Возник вопрос по `Spring`-у. 
Есть класс контроллер,который по заданному url должен отдавать jsp.
Вот код

```
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                                  HttpServletResponse response) {

    return new ModelAndView("index1.jsp");
}
```

Однако появляется ошибка

> timestamp=Wed May 04 10:00:14 MSK 2016, status=500, error=Internal
>   Server Error, exception=javax.servlet.ServletException,
>   message=Circular view path [index1.jsp]: would dispatch back to the
>   current handler URL [/exercise/index1.jsp] again. Check your
>   ViewResolver setup!

Понял,что скорее всего надо прописать свойство `suffix=".jsp"`,но там ничего изменять нельзя.Можете подсказать "где собака зарыта"? Если прописывать без расширения `jsp`,то тоже не работает.
Заранее благодарен

Comment: Вообще-то в ошибке говориться, что зациклились ваши jsp, index.jsp передаёт управление /exercise/index1.jsp, а тот в свою очередь назад в index1,jsp.

Comment: @ResponseBody здесь лишняя если ты возвращаешь вьюху, а не тело ответа. Плюс неплохо бы было привести полный код класса и настройки для jsp